# d3js, apply force to array of objects

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Im currently trying to apply a force with d3.js to an array of objects. But the force only gets applied to the last object. The array contains 5 svg elements.

The code for applying the force looks like this.

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(arr)
    .links([])
    .size([svgWidth, svgHeight]);

    arr[i] = force;
}
```

Comment: What is `nodes`? You're creating 5 different force layouts here.

Comment: nodes is suppoed to be "arr". my mistake. yeah, i have 5 svg:s in the html and need to apply one force for each one of them.

Comment: Thing is that i have this 5 svgs that gets populated. I need to apply the force on all 5 of them. Is that possible?

Comment: The way you're applying the force layout is fundamentally wrong -- have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)?